# how to change Action name according to language

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am building website with Turkish as default and English languages. I have an action for Turkish language like below

```
/Home/Sertifika
```

and when a user selects English language, I want to show the action like below

```
/Home/Certificate
```

But I dont want to create 2 actions called /Sertifika and /Certificate. How can I manage to have one action with two different names?

thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by an action?

Comment: You might be interested in this post: https://www.strathweb.com/2015/11/localized-routes-with-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6/ or this Github project: https://github.com/Dresel/RouteLocalization

Comment: You can check :http://afana.me/archive/2011/01/14/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx/